# Django unit testing: Separating unit tests without querying the database multiple times

Tags: django, unit-testing

I have a pair of tests like this:

## Make sure a task's deletion status initializes as None

```
def test_initial_task_deletion_status_is_none(self):
    unfinished_task = Task.objects.get(tasked_with="Unfinished Test")
    self.assertIsNone(unfinished_task.delete_status)

# Make sure a task's deletion status changes appropriately
def test_unfinished_task_deletion_status_updates_appropriately(self):
    unfinished_task = Task.objects.get(tasked_with="Unfinished Test")
    unfinished_task.timed_delete(delta=.1)
    self.assertIs(unfinished_task.delete_status, "Marked for Deletion")
```

This will go on, but I'll have `unfinished_task = Task.objects.get(tasked_with="Unfinished Test")` at the beginning of every one. Is there a way to split these types of things into separate tests, but use the same query result?

Comment: No you can't, because the database is destroyed and recreated for each test anyway. You can put the query into `setUp` and assign the result to an instance variable, but it'll still be executed each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using [Django's testing framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/overview/), then you can do this using `setUp()`.
More about `unittest.TestCase.setUp()` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)

So your updated snippet would look like:

```py
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.unfinished_task = Task.objects.get(tasked_with="Unfinished Test")

    def test_initial_task_deletion_status_is_none(self): 
        self.assertIsNone(self.unfinished_task.delete_status)

    # Make sure a task's deletion status changes appropriately
    def test_unfinished_task_deletion_status_updates_appropriately(self):
        self.unfinished_task.timed_delete(delta=.1)
        self.assertIs(self.unfinished_task.delete_status, "Marked for Deletion")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place the repeated line in the `setUp` method, and that will make your code less repetitive, but as DanielRoseman pointed out, it will still be run for each test, so you won't be using the same query result.

You can place it in the [`setUpTestData`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData) method, and it will be run only once, before all the tests in `MyTestCase`, but then your `unfinished_task` object will be a class variable, shared across all the tests.  In-memory modifications made to the object during one test will carry over into subsequent tests, and that is not what you want.

In read-only tests, using `setUpTestData` is a good way to cut out unnecessary queries, but if you're going to be modifying the objects, you'll want to start fresh each time.